# MVC3 C# custom validation message sending from server side

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, custom-validators

Good day. May be it is wrong way but it was the fastest way. So:

I have a model which store IP address (NetworkMask) as long (integer) (stored in mssql table)
And then I need to implement entering and correcting IP address
I added not mapped field (IPv4NetworkMask) into model:

```
    [NotMapped]
    public string IPv4NetworkMask{
        get{
            return ExtIP.LongToIPv4(NetworkMask);
        }
        set{
            NetworkMask=ExtIP.StringToIPv4(value);
        }
    }
```

and into view:

```
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NetworkMask)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IPv4NetworkMask)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IPv4NetworkMask)
        </div>
```

Now everything works fine and when user entered incorrect network address I got an Exception inside StringToIPv4 and execution goes out of controller by

```
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(NewModelObj);
```

But on client side I got message: "The value 'fdgdfgdf' is invalid."
How can I change this message to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it on the business layer, you can use a [custom validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

for example:

```
public static ValidationResult ValidateIP(string inputIP)
{
   bool isValid = false;

    try {
        ExtIP.StringToIPv4(inputIP);
        isValid = true;
    }
    catch {
    }


    if (isValid)
    {
      return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
    else
    {
      return new ValidationResult(
          "Ip is not in a correct format.");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, I've just implement with custom attribute and data annotations. Some good code sample: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs

Answer (score 0):

I found the simplest way:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IPv4NetworkMask, "You have entered incorrect IP")
```